# Is the "obsolete" flag applicable even to comments that have already re-written as answer?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

In ["Agreed" or "agreed to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39516/agreed-that-or-agreed-to-that) there is a comment that has been re-written as [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39516/agreed-that-or-agreed-to-that/39533#39533).

Is flagging the comment as obsolete correct, in this case?
In which other cases should a comment be marked as obsolete?
Does that have a meaning, or do moderators see it just as background noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is flagging the comment as obsolete correct, in this case?

Yes.

> In which other cases should a comment be marked as obsolete?

When the comment is no longer valuable, such as when a comment suggests a rephrasing of the question that is subsequently edited into the question.

> Does that have a meaning, or do moderators see it just as background noise?

We delete obsolete comments, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: With the last question I simply mean to ask if flagging such comments is something that moderators don't like because there are too many comments that are flagged without a reason, or because it's preferable to focus on something else. I didn't doubt obsolete comments are deleted; I just thought that it could be considered secondary, if there are already too comments that are wrongly flagged.

Comment: @kiam Always feel free to flag; truth be told, we don't actually get a lot of flagged comments, so it's perfectly fine.